# C# reflection. Target exception was unhandled

Tags: c#, exception, reflection

```
NetworkElementCountersFactory factory=new NetworkElementCountersFactory();
List<NetworkElementCounters> neCountersList= new List<NetworkElementCounters>();
NetworkElementCounters neCounters;
while (reader.Read())
{
    i = 4;
    neCounters = factory.getInstance(tableName, reader.GetInt32(0), reader.GetDateTime(1), reader.GetDateTime(2), reader.GetInt32(3));
    foreach (var v in neCounters.Fields)
    {
        v.GetType().GetProperty("CounterValue").SetValue(neCounters.GetType(), reader.GetValue(i), null);
        i++;
    }
    neCountersList.Add(neCounters);
}
```

I receive the exception here:

```
v.GetType().GetProperty("CounterValue").SetValue(neCounters.GetType(), reader.GetValue(i), null);
```

Comment: Please provide the **complete** exception, with stacktrace and inner exception (essentially the output of the `Exception.ToString()` method).

Comment: target exception . object does not match terget type.

Comment: @andrew "object does not match target type" - yes, because (as noted) you are passing the `Type`, not the target.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks very wrong:

```
.SetValue(neCounters.GetType(), {whatever}, null);
```

That means you are trying to assign this on a `Type` instance. You should be passing the target object here, or `null` if it is a `static` property. It *looks* like this should be:

```
.SetValue(neCounters, {whatever}, null);
```

but then it would be easier to use:

```
neCounters.CounterValue = ...
// v.CounterValue = ... // <=== might be this instead - confusing context
```

maybe via `dynamic` if there is some complexity here:

```
dynamic obj = neCounters;
// dynamic obj = v; // <=== might be this instead - confusing context
obj.CounterValue = reader.GetValue(i);
```

Comment: @andrew I've refreshed - the question still clearly passes `newCounters.GetType()` as the target...?

Comment: v.GetType().GetProperty("CounterValue").SetValue(neCounters, reader.GetValue(i), null);

Comment: @andrew k... try it with `SetValue(v, ...)`. It is very hard for us to understand the context here without types etc

Comment: i will try with dynamic. NetworkElementCounter is a supertype, and i create a subtype, because in every subtype i have a different type of CounterValue

Comment: @andrew my concern is: you get the property from `v`; it is unclear how `v`, `neCounters` and `.Fields` all interact, so we're playing "guess" a bit here...

Comment: sorry, my mistake, i think i solved it. there is v and not neCounters

Comment: and because of that it was mismatch of types. thanks for your help